# Indictment and prosecution in different U.S. districts

Tags: criminal-procedure, indictment

Can a person be prosecuted in any district other than the district in which the original  indictment was filed? Does this require some sort of special procedure?

Comment: The trial of the Oklahoma City terrorist Timothy McVeigh was famously transferred from Oklahoma to Colorado at the request of the defense. If ever there was a case where, in the district where the crime took place, the public felt intensely emotional about the matter, this was it. But I don't think it can be done without the defendant's consent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Rule 20](https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-523-rule-20-transfers-prisoners-district-plea-and-sentence)**

Federal Rule of Criminal Procedure 20 allows criminal cases to transfer from one district to another for the "limited purposes of acceptance of guilty or nolo contendere pleas and sentencing."

**[Rule 21](https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-530-rule-21-transfers-district-trial)**

Federal Rule of Criminal Procedure 21 allows a defendant to make a motion to transfer the criminal case to another district for the trial if "(a) the atmosphere is so prejudicial the defendant cannot obtain a fair and impartial trial within the district in which the action is brought or (b) for the convenience of the parties and witnesses, if in the interest of justice."